# Is it possible to copy a power bi report (pbix file) and change the content without affecting the original rapport?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Say that I already have a PBI report which is posted to the service/workspace. I want to use the same dataset and Query, but build new visualisation to make a different/additional report. Is it possible to make a copy of the pbix file and publish it to the service with a new name without affecting the original PBI report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can [save a copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-copy-reports) of the report, either by opening the report and click on File -> Save a copy:

[image]

or by using the ellipsis button in the workspace itself:

[image]

This will make a copy of the report, but it will use the original dataset (i.e. there will be only 1 dataset and 2 reports).

You can also create a new report and [use the original dataset as a data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets).

And of course, you can [download the report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-export-to-pbix), rename it, and publish it again (in which case you will get a copy of the dataset too).